# Is there anyway to get rid of the watermark after installing Windows Media Center on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8

Is there anyway to get rid of the watermark after installing Windows Media Center on Windows 8?

[image]

Comment: TheX: since you figured it out, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

See if this Software works. I will continue my search to see if there's a registry fix for this.

[image]

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1837246

Comment: actually I figured it out... all I had to do was change my theme... and it disappeared...

Comment: @mwong Please don't post links as answers, write the answer found in at the site, and credit the source.  This way the answer is useful even if the linked content goes away.

Comment: Okay I will make sure to reflect on that for my next answer.

Comment: @mwong you can edit your own answer to improve it, but I did it for you this time.